# AngularJs 1.3 check if controller exists

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I have the following code in a large Angular project:

```
$stateProvider.state('my-app', {
    url : '/',
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: '/?page=/home',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }
    }
});
```

I know I can remove the controller using `delete element['views']['content@']['controller'];` and init with `element` afterwards but how can I check if `HomeController` exists? After a day of researching. No working solution seems to exist in Angular.

Comment: just use console.log('invoking HomeController'); in your home controller when ever the controller invokes it will be printer in your browser log.

Comment: I want to check if it exists because some controllers will not exist though.

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove controllers. This should be done by angular.

But you could set some injected service variable on controller creation and clear it 'on destroy'. I.e. to do something like:

```
angular
  .module('something')
  .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'myGlobalService'];
function HomeController($scope, myGlobalService) {

  myGlobalService.isHomeControllerPresent = true;

  $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    myGlobalService.isHomeControllerPresent = undefined;
  });
}
```

But it's more a hack than 'Angular style'.

If you have access to $scope and you know controller name (i.e. **ng-controller="homeCtrl as HomeController"** or **controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'**) then you could just check:

```
if ($scope.homeCtrl) {
   ...
}
```

because any controller is a part of its scope - each controller is 'attached' to its scope by name.

But once again: no one should remove controllers except angular ;)